# How do I load data from a StreamingBody object using Insert to Code to pandas in Watson Studio?

Tags: pandas, jupyter-notebook, data-science-experience, watson-studio

The `Insert to Code` feature enables you to access data stored in Cloud Object Storage when working in Jupyter notebooks in Watson Studio. Some file types (e.g. txt files) will have just StreamingBody and Credentials as insert to code options:

[image: Screenshot of Insert to Code functionality]

How can I use the `StreamingBody` object to access my data?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

These code snippets do not always get you the whole way to access your data. For the `Insert StreamingBody object` option, you can load the data into a pandas dataframe using `io.BytesIO`, for example:

```
import io
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_table(io.BytesIO(streaming_body_1.read()))
```

where `streaming_body_1` is a boto3 client `get_object()['Body']`

Answer (score 1):

If anyone else has stumbled upon this answer when trying to upload a csv, check that you haven't forgotten to convert your .xls or .xlsx to .csv.

Once it's in CSV, it will automatically create your dataframe for you.